# javascript variable pass by url

Tags: javascript

```
<script language=JavaScript>

function add()
 {

***Z***=3025;
}
</script>
<form........>
<input type ="submit" onClick="add()"
</form>

<a herf="http://XXXXXXXX.co.uk/XXXX.qmd?pack_id=***Z***"></a>
```

need to put the Z***emphasized text*** value in the URL
The value of z will be produce by another java script function ADD

Comment: herf is a typo? Must be href.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the value of ***Z*** in the add() function and pass that value to the querystring in the URL. I assume you want a client side implementation here.

It wont work that way because the variable ***Z*** is not recognized outside the `<script>` block, so the `<A href>` does not know of such a variable.

What will work however, is if you create the whole URL within the function and submit it from within the function.

Your code will look like this:

In the add() function, the URL is constructed and browser address is instantly changed to that location.

```
<script>
function add()         { 

var Z="3025"; 
document.location="http://XXXXXXXX.co.uk/XXXX.qmd?pack_id="+Z;
} 
</script> 
<form> 
    <input type ="submit" onClick="javascript:add()" value="my button"> 
    </form>
```

If you actually want to just set the variables into the `<A href>` so that these can be clicked by the user at a later time, you'll probably need to use [some **not recommended** techniques such as document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) of the full  url.

Read the above link for why not to go down that route.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be generating this at the server side, so that html is ready and no manipulation in JavaScript is needed. However:

give id to your link:

```
<a href="http://XXXXXXXX.co.uk/XXXX.qmd?pack_id=" id="cool_link"></a>
```

and change its `href` attribute:

```
<script>
    var Z = 3025;
    document.getElementById("cool_link").href += "***" + Z + "***";
</script>
```

if you're using jQuery syntax may be simplified a bit.